# Android get current count returned by cursor

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I need your help. I have a listview and search edittext, when I type to search for a record and matches from db, it displays all records. However, if no record matches it just displays nothing. What I wanna do is to display a message **No Records Found**

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher (){

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {


        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {


        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {


            adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());

        }

    });

 adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

            String searchBy = constraint.toString();

            if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
                Log.e("Cursor", "" + "Empty result");
            }

            return dbHelper.searchProduct(searchBy, telco);

        }
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

```
  public Cursor searchProduct(String product, String telco)
        {

            final String MY_QUERY 
              = "SELECT * " +
                "FROM products " + 
                "WHERE telco_code = '" + telco + "' " +
                "AND product_code LIKE '%" + product + "%' " + // LIKE '%
                "AND product_description LIKE '%" + product + "%';";

            Cursor localCursor =
                    this.myDataBase.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);

            if (localCursor != null)
              localCursor.moveToFirst();
            return localCursor;

        }
```

Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `cursor.getCount()` ?

Comment: lol @answers ...it is obvious ... problem is that it is done in wrong place ... also -1(please fix the question) you didn't not provide **where you wana *display a message*** neither what you are using (plain ListView? ListFragment/ListActivity?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using this:

```
  adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {

        @Override
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

            String searchBy = constraint.toString();

            Cursor newCursor = dbHelper.searchProduct(searchBy, telco);

            if(newCursor.getCount() == 0) {
                Log.e("Cursor", "Empty" );
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvHeader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tvHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_products));
                    }
                });
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }

            return newCursor;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if(cursor == null)
```

with

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() == 0)
```

**EDIT:**

Implement the `runQuery()` method this way:

```
@Override
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

        String searchBy = constraint.toString();

        Cursor  cursor = dbHelper.searchProduct(searchBy, telco);

        if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() == 0){

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("No Records Found")
                .setMessage("No records are available.")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
            }

        return cursor;

    }
```

Try this. This should work.

Comment: he can't ... question is: *What I wanna do is to display a message No Records Found* ... did you read it?

Comment: Yes, I'm still trying to figure out where to put the message

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes: can you provide the code of your `searchProduct()` method ?

Comment: @bEtTyBarnes: please see edited answer ... I have assumed that you are using an `Activity`. If you are using a `Fragment` then please replace `new AlertDialog.Builder(this)` with `new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())`.

Comment: @ZygoteInit no, but I do not want AlertDialog, only a text

Comment: by "text" you mean a toast or a logcat message ??

Comment: @ZygoteInit display a text in a TextView. That's what I meant.

Comment: oh ok ... then instead of showing `AlertDialog`, just call `TextView.settext()` in its place :)

Comment: @ZygoteInit I tried showing and hiding of textview using runOnUIThread. Thanks for helping by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Change following line

```
if(cursor == null)
```

to

```
if(cursor != null &&cursor.getCount() == 0)
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ListView's empty view functionality.

In the layout where you have your ListView placed, you also add a view that you will show when the ListView is empty. Then when initializing (in code) the ListView you assign the empty view.

The ListView will now show and hide the empty view depending on if the ListView has data loaded or not.

activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout ... >    

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emptyView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Nothing to show..." />

</Frameayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.emptyView));
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Really, why the downvote? My answer is exactly what the original question wants but didn't know how to ask. The question is: 'when there are no search matches, I want to display the message: "no records found."' The ListView's EmptyView does precisely that. The accepted answer reproduces exactly the EmptyView functionality, namely: check the result query's count and set the visibility of the 'no records found' text view accordingly. Using `listview.setEmptyView(tvHeader)` you can replace all that with a single line.